# how to resolve warnings when running BLC?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I get following warnings when I try to run BLC demo application. Although there is no known issue caused by these warnings but I would like to know how can I resolve these warnings?

```
[ WARN] 23:05:05 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.copy.DirectCopyClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 23:05:05 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.convert.EntityMarkerClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 23:05:05 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.copy.DirectCopyClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 23:05:13 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [blSandBoxElements]; using defaults.
[ WARN] 23:05:29 DefaultFilterChainValidator - Possible error: Filters at position 12 and 13 are both instances of org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -javaagent:/path/of/spring-instrument.jar into your Tomcat or any server VM args.

It has everything to do with spring instrument when coming from BroadleafCommerce

Answer (score -1):

may be you need to add "-javaagent:spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" into vm args.

Comment: these warnings are not related to spring instrument library